# How to remove ACLS from Kafka using Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to remove ACLS from KAfka using Java program. But on removal security check is asking

> Are you sure you want to remove ACLs:

I am looking for either disable this security check or force removal option.

Comment: Seems there is no force removal option. It invokes 'Console.readLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y")' expecting you to confirm from within a console.

Comment: thanks for your quick resonse, I was able resolve the issue. posted my solution below

Answer (score 3):

Upgraded to Kafka 0.10.1.0 from 0.10.0.0 where force delete option available in `AclCommand` (scala component). Add `--force` parameter after `--remove`.

Exactly working syntax:

```
String[] cmdPArm = {"--authorizer-properties", "zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181",
                    "--remove", "--force", "--allow-principal", "User:*",
                    "--allow-host", "17.129.0.99",
                    "--operation", "Read",  "--operation", "Write",
                    "--topic", "myTopic"};
AclCommand.main(cmdPArm);
```

Comment: Yes, Kafka 0.10.1.0 does offer a "--force" option to avoid all the prompting.